# Render Newly Visible Portion Upon Scrolling on JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I have a large JPanel embedded in a JScrollPane. When I move the scrollbar, I notice that the visible portion does not render itself and I get glitches. Whereas when I resize the frame, I can see the new visible portions rendered. So I need to know which methods are fired upon frame resize to repaint the view. What listeners/methods should I use?

Answer (score 2):

> So I need to know which methods are fired upon frame resize

You don't need to know that. All you need to do is change the value of the scrollbar or the position of viewport and the component should repaint itself properly. If it is not painting properly, then you have a problem with something else. Maybe

1. incorrect custom painting code
2. the code is not invoked on the EDT

If those suggestsion doen't help then you need to post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem because we can't keep guessing what your code is doing.

Comment: +1 for a more complete answer. Especially important bit related to EDT.

Answer (score 1):

Did you revalidate the panel?
It might be that something is not right in the code of yours.
I have been using lots of scrolls and never had an issue as you describe.
Maybe a code sample showing the problem would be nice.

Good luck, Boro